# Crop black bounding box from an Image using python

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I am trying to take an image that contains some data and a black box with a drawing within the black box.
The goal is to crop everything from the image except the drawing within the black box.

I implemented a script using Canny edge detection to detect the edges and get the max contour so that i would know where the box is and could crop it out.
This works great except for when someone draws outside of the box.
I need to be able to allow people to draw outside the box and have the script ignore whatever is outside the box and crop to just what is inside the box (excluding the box edges)

I have tried Canny edge detection but it fails if anything is drawn outside the box.

```
 image = cv2.imread(processed_path)
 grayScaled = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayScaled, (3,3), 0) 
 edges = cv2.Canny(image=img_blur, threshold1=100, threshold2=200)
 contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 border = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
 x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(border)
 cropped_image = image[y+27:y+h-22, x+27:x+w-20]
```

This works well except when someone draws outside the box.

Attached is the image im attempting it on as well as the edges that are spit out.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The image seems so neatly scanned. If that is always the case. Why don't you estimate the inner pixel positions of the box and crop that?

Comment: Im covering my bases on this one, theres a possibility for skewing when scanned in.